# Why Monit does not work with my MySQL configuration file?

Tags: mysql, debian-squeeze, monit

I'm using a custom configuration file for mysql in /etc/mysql/conf.d/myfile.cnf

The contents of the file

```
[client]
port        = 3306
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

[mysqld_safe]
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice        = 0

[mysqld]
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir = /usr
datadir = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
language    = /usr/share/mysql/english
skip-external-locking
bind-address        = 127.0.0.1

bulk_insert_buffer_size = 8M
connect_timeout=10
interactive_timeout=50
join_buffer=1M
key_buffer=250M
max_allowed_packet=16M
max_connect_errors=10
max_connections=100
max_heap_table_size = 32M
myisam_sort_buffer_size=96M
query_cache_limit = 4M
query_cache_size = 250M
query_cache_type = 1
query_prealloc_size = 65K
query_alloc_block_size = 128K
read_buffer_size=1M
read_rnd_buffer_size=768K
#record_buffer_size=1M
#safe-show-database
#skip-innodb
#skip-locking
skip-networking
sort_buffer=1M
table_cache=4096
thread_cache_size=1024
thread_concurrency=8
tmp_table_size = 32M
wait_timeout=500
# for slow queries, comment when not used
#log-slow-queries=/var/log/mysql-slow.log
#long_query_time=1
#log-queries-not-using-indexes

[mysqld_safe]
nice = -5
open_files_limit = 8192
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock



[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 16M
[myisamchk]
key_buffer = 64M
sort_buffer = 64M
read_buffer = 16M
write_buffer = 16M
```

What's wrong?

If you use the configuration file default for mysql, Monit runs smoothly

My sistem is Debian Squeeze 6.0.x and Mysql Server version: 5.1.66-0+squeeze1 (Debian)

The error is monit status: "status Connection failed" and "Port Response time connection failed to 127.0.0.1:3306 [DEFAULT via TCP]"

My configuration Monit Mysql

```
...
check process mysql with pidfile /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
  group database
  start program = "/etc/init.d/mysql start"
  stop program = "/etc/init.d/mysql stop"
  if failed host 127.0.0.1 port 3306 then restart
  if 5 restarts within 5 cycles then timeout
...
```

Comment: helps if you should your monit config for mysql

Answer (score 4):

On Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, I found that `pid-file` and `socket` were commented out in `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`. I uncommented those two lines then restarted mysql with `service mysql restart` and monit with `service monit restart` and monit was successfully able to monitor the `mysqld` process.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is it is this line

```
if failed host 127.0.0.1 port 3306 then restart
```

MySQL will block a host if it hits 10 (I think) bad connections in a row. I think it's working until the 10th check then it starts to fail. There is nothing wrong with the rest of it. Try fixing it like this

```
if failed host 127.0.0.1 port 3306 protocol mysql then restart
```

You should also run

```
mysqladmin flush-hosts
```

That will clear the banned hosts

Comment: Connection failed :(

Comment: recent versions of MySQL block monit even if `protocol mysql` is used