# Monit can't detect MySQL

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, monit

The Monit webinterfcae is showing: Execution failed | Does not exist

netstat is giving me:

```
sudo netstat -lnp | grep mysql
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33060         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4643/mysqld
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4643/mysqld
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     90220    4643/mysqld          /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     90222    4643/mysqld          /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

And monit -v (if this helps):

```
Process Name          = mysqld
 Group                = mysql, database
 Pid file             = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
 Monitoring mode      = active
 On reboot            = start
 Start program        = '/etc/init.d/mysql start' timeout 30 s
 Stop program         = '/etc/init.d/mysql stop' timeout 30 s
 Existence            = if does not exist then restart
 Depends on Service   = mysql_rc
 Depends on Service   = mysql_bin
 Port                 = if failed [localhost]:3306 type TCP/IP protocol MYSQL with timeout 15 s for 3 times within 4 cycles then restart
 Unix Socket          = if failed /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock type TCP protocol MYSQL with timeout 5 s for 3 times within 4 cycles then restart
 Timeout              = If restarted 5 times within 5 cycle(s) then unmonitor

File Name             = mysql_bin
 Group                = mysql
 Path                 = /usr/sbin/mysqld
 Monitoring mode      = active
 On reboot            = start
 Existence            = if does not exist then restart
 Checksum             = if failed defc97a98deb37905c97d9b5a09f9f13(MD5) then unmonitor
 Permission           = if failed 0755 then unmonitor
 UID                  = if failed 0 then unmonitor
 GID                  = if failed 0 then unmonitor

File Name             = mysql_rc
 Group                = mysql
 Path                 = /etc/init.d/mysql
 Monitoring mode      = active
 On reboot            = start
 Existence            = if does not exist then restart
 Checksum             = if failed 89a1a5b6ad710389112802fc3fbb81e1(MD5) then unmonitor
 Permission           = if failed 0755 then unmonitor
 UID                  = if failed 0 then unmonitor
 GID                  = if failed 0 then unmonitor
```

So even if mysql is running and active Monit can't detect it. I set the symlink with:

`sudo ln -s /etc/monit/conf-available/mysql /etc/monit/conf-enabled/`

Using Ubuntu 20.04

EDIT :

monit status:

```
Process 'mysqld'
  status                       Not monitored
  monitoring status            Not monitored
  monitoring mode              active
  on reboot                    start
  data collected               Sun, 20 Dec 2020 00:00:29

File 'mysql_bin'
  status                       OK
  monitoring status            Monitored
  monitoring mode              active
  on reboot                    start
  permission                   755
  uid                          0
  gid                          0
  size                         63.7 MB
  access timestamp             Mon, 21 Dec 2020 11:53:36
  change timestamp             Thu, 17 Dec 2020 11:52:00
  modify timestamp             Thu, 26 Nov 2020 12:03:42
  checksum                     defc97a98deb37905c97d9b5a09f9f13 (MD5)
  data collected               Mon, 21 Dec 2020 16:32:35

File 'mysql_rc'
  status                       OK
  monitoring status            Monitored
  monitoring mode              active
  on reboot                    start
  permission                   755
  uid                          0
  gid                          0
  size                         5.5 kB
  access timestamp             Mon, 21 Dec 2020 11:53:37
  change timestamp             Thu, 17 Dec 2020 11:52:05
  modify timestamp             Wed, 06 Nov 2019 18:34:43
  checksum                     89a1a5b6ad710389112802fc3fbb81e1 (MD5)
  data collected               Mon, 21 Dec 2020 16:32:35
```

The monit logs show as follows, nothing irregular to me. Ignore the mail error:

```
[UTC Dec 21 16:37:10] info     : 'apache' monitor on user request
[UTC Dec 21 16:37:10] info     : 'mysqld' monitor on user request
[UTC Dec 21 16:37:10] info     : 'nginx' monitor on user request
[UTC Dec 21 16:37:10] info     : 'inf-education-67' monitor on user request
[UTC Dec 21 16:37:10] info     : 'apache_rc' monitor on user request
[UTC Dec 21 16:37:10] info     : 'apache_bin' monitor on user request
[UTC Dec 21 16:37:10] info     : 'mysql_rc' monitor on user request
[UTC Dec 21 16:37:10] info     : 'mysql_bin' monitor on user request
[UTC Dec 21 16:37:10] info     : 'nginx_rc' monitor on user request
[UTC Dec 21 16:37:10] info     : 'nginx_bin' monitor on user request
[UTC Dec 21 16:37:10] info     : Monit daemon with PID 900 awakened
[UTC Dec 21 16:37:10] info     : Awakened by User defined signal 1
[UTC Dec 21 16:37:10] error    : Mail: Mailserver response error -- 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
[UTC Dec 21 16:37:10] error    : SMTP: Mailserver response error -- 535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials f77sm22188901wmf.42 - gsmtp
[UTC Dec 21 16:37:10] error    : Alert handler failed, retry scheduled for next cycle
[UTC Dec 21 16:37:10] info     : 'nginx_bin' monitor action done
[UTC Dec 21 16:37:11] error    : Mail: Mailserver response error -- 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
[UTC Dec 21 16:37:11] error    : SMTP: Mailserver response error -- 535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials y63sm24571380wmd.21 - gsmtp
[UTC Dec 21 16:37:11] error    : Event queue is full
[UTC Dec 21 16:37:11] error    : Aborting event - queue over quota
[UTC Dec 21 16:37:11] info     : 'nginx_rc' monitor action done
[UTC Dec 21 16:37:11] error    : Mail: Mailserver response error -- 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
[UTC Dec 21 16:37:11] error    : SMTP: Mailserver response error -- 535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials o125sm24541891wmo.30 - gsmtp
[UTC Dec 21 16:37:11] error    : Event queue is full
[UTC Dec 21 16:37:11] error    : Aborting event - queue over quota
[UTC Dec 21 16:37:11] info     : 'mysql_bin' monitor action done
[UTC Dec 21 16:37:11] error    : Mail: Mailserver response error -- 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
[UTC Dec 21 16:37:11] error    : SMTP: Mailserver response error -- 535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials m2sm22734832wml.34 - gsmtp
[UTC Dec 21 16:37:11] error    : Event queue is full
[UTC Dec 21 16:37:11] error    : Aborting event - queue over quota
[UTC Dec 21 16:37:11] info     : 'mysql_rc' monitor action done
[UTC Dec 21 16:37:11] error    : Mail: Mailserver response error -- 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
[UTC Dec 21 16:37:11] error    : SMTP: Mailserver response error -- 535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials s3sm2848477wmc.44 - gsmtp
[UTC Dec 21 16:37:11] error    : Event queue is full
[UTC Dec 21 16:37:11] error    : Aborting event - queue over quota
[UTC Dec 21 16:37:11] info     : 'apache_bin' monitor action done
[UTC Dec 21 16:37:12] error    : Mail: Mailserver response error -- 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
[UTC Dec 21 16:37:12] error    : SMTP: Mailserver response error -- 535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials 125sm22297314wmc.27 - gsmtp
[UTC Dec 21 16:37:12] error    : Event queue is full
[UTC Dec 21 16:37:12] error    : Aborting event - queue over quota
[UTC Dec 21 16:37:12] info     : 'apache_rc' monitor action done
[UTC Dec 21 16:37:12] error    : Mail: Mailserver response error -- 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
[UTC Dec 21 16:37:12] error    : SMTP: Mailserver response error -- 535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials o23sm30549332wro.57 - gsmtp
[UTC Dec 21 16:37:12] error    : Event queue is full
[UTC Dec 21 16:37:12] error    : Aborting event - queue over quota
[UTC Dec 21 16:37:12] info     : 'inf-education-67' monitor action done
[UTC Dec 21 16:37:12] error    : Mail: Mailserver response error -- 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
[UTC Dec 21 16:37:12] error    : SMTP: Mailserver response error -- 535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials v20sm28999905wra.19 - gsmtp
[UTC Dec 21 16:37:12] error    : Event queue is full
[UTC Dec 21 16:37:12] error    : Aborting event - queue over quota
[UTC Dec 21 16:37:12] info     : 'nginx' monitor action done
[UTC Dec 21 16:37:12] error    : Mail: Mailserver response error -- 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
[UTC Dec 21 16:37:12] error    : SMTP: Mailserver response error -- 535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials k1sm27935712wrn.46 - gsmtp
[UTC Dec 21 16:37:12] error    : Event queue is full
[UTC Dec 21 16:37:12] error    : Aborting event - queue over quota
[UTC Dec 21 16:37:12] info     : 'mysqld' monitor action done
```

Comment: Did you reload monit ? What is the output of command "monit status" or "monit summary" ? what is monit showing as error in the log file ?

Comment: @DevOps I edited the question. Appreciate all help!

Comment: (1) after being unmonitored once (and statefile activated) monit will not enable a service again per default. (2) is `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid` present and has mysql's PID as content?

Comment: @boppy No, that file doesn't exist. There's just mysql.sock, mysql.sock.lock and the same for mysqlx.

Comment: But monit is configured to check for a process with a PID stored in that file. So monit cannot find the pid file - therefore also not the process (and thinks it is down for that reason). Then it trys starting the process what must fail... So: find the correct pidfile (see my.cnf of mysql), fix the path in the `mysql` file and you're good to go.

Answer (score 4):

[Tyler](https://serverfault.com/users/618191/tyler) answers on [another question](https://serverfault.com/questions/487495/why-monit-does-not-work-with-my-mysql-configuration-file) about this:

> On Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, I found that pid-file and socket were commented
> out in `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`. I uncommented those two
> lines then restarted mysql with `service mysql restart` and monit with
> `service monit restart` and monit was successfully able to monitor the
> mysqld process.

It's worked for me, BTW Thank you @Tyler (I can't upvote and comment there)

Comment: in my case, pid exists - but monit still failed: `-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 7 Mar 26 11:07 /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid`

Comment: Thanks, uncommenting the pid file location setting in the mysql config did the trick for me as well.